# How to check whether given website URL run NGINX and what version if it is available?

Tags: node.js

How to check whether the given website URL runs NGINX and what version if it is available.

Comment: There is no reliable way to get it. Even if it's the only application between a client and back-end, it's a good practice to hide at least the version of the server to avoid targeted attacks.

Answer (score 4):

You can see this information in the HTTP header `Server`.

In Chrome devtools for example:

[image: DevTools screenshot]

Command line example:

```sh
$ curl -sI https://nginx.com | grep Server:
Server: nginx/1.17.3
```

Since you have tagged your question with `node.js`, here is a node.js demo doing the same thing:

```js
import fetch from 'node-fetch'

async function getServerInfo (url) {
  const response = await fetch(url)
  const fullServerHeader = response.headers.get('Server')
  const [serverName, serverVersion] = fullServerHeader?.split('/')
  return { fullServerHeader, serverName, serverVersion }
}

console.log(await getServerInfo('https://nginx.com'))
// Outputs:
// {
//   fullServerHeader: 'nginx/1.17.3',
//   serverName: 'nginx',
//   serverVersion: '1.17.3'
// }
```

Note that this works only if the server header is not disabled. Furthermore, there may be other reverse proxies or CDNs or firewalls in front of nginx, then the server header may also be masked or overwritten. So, **there is no guarantee that this information is returned**!

Answer (score 0):

Response can contains **Server** header. The Server header contains information about the software used by the origin server to handle the request.

But you should understand this is not mandatory header.

See for more details: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Server
https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx/how-to-remove-the-server-header-in-nginx

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that this question is tagged with [node.js](/questions/tagged/node.js).
Nevertheless I think it's useful to mention that on the command line or in a Bash script you can get the server information with `curl` using its `--head` option (assuming that it is not hidden, as others have pointed out). Example:

`curl --head https://www.nginx.com`

which returns lots of information, I cut most of it, the last line is what you should look for in this case:

```
HTTP/2 200 
date: Thu, 05 Oct 2023 12:14:21 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
vary: Accept-Encoding
...
server: nginx
```

You could parse the server name out e.g. with `awk`, like this:

`curl -s --head https://www.nginx.com | awk '/^[sS]erver/ { print $2; }'`

The `awk` pattern is `^[sS]erver` because Apache spells its "Server" line with a capital "S". The `-s` option makes `curl` operating "silently".